# Android GridView OnItemClickListener area

Tags: android

I have a GridView that displays a bunch of thumbnail images. All looks good, but when I click on an item, only the upper right hand portion of the image will register the onitemclicklistener call. If I click the lower left hand corner, nothing happens. When I fill the gridview with many images, clicking on certain images will trigger the call at the wrong position.

Here is some relevant code from the adapter:

```
imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
final float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (155 * scale + 0.5f);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(pixels, pixels));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
```

Here is the listener code:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

Intent intent = new Intent(MobialGrid.this,MobialImageInd.class);
intent.putExtra("image", file[position].getAbsolutePath());
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Here is the grid xml:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="160dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:paddingBottom="15dp"    
android:background="@drawable/dark_bg_repeat"
/>
```

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Where are you setting listener? Post full code

Comment: I have done some additional testing (Nexus 7 and many emulator devices) and I believe this to be an issue specific to the Galaxy S4. Can anyone else confirm who has this device?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the listener on the imageviews in your adapter, that might help...